# How to unpack data using byte objects in python

Tags: python, object, struct, byte

I am trying to unpack a specific piece of data from an encoded file. The data is a type int32.

My approach was to try and read each line of the file and if a section of that lines size matches the size of '

```
with open(r2sFile2, encoding="latin-1") as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        for i in range(0, len(line)):
            text = line.encode('latin-1')


            fmt = text[0: i+1]
            print(sys.getsizeof(fmt))
            if (sys.getsizeof(fmt) == 4):
                 PacketSize  = struct.unpack('<I', fmt)
                 if PacketSize == 'BTH0':
                     print("Identifier Found")
```

I am encountering 1 problem so far, the first is that the sys.getsizeof(fmt) [ which reads the size of the line segment ] returns a size always higher than the size required [ 4 ]. Maybe I have to convert every byte object into an int32( if possible )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot open a file using an encoding and also read raw bytes from the same stream.  Specifying an encoding will convert those bytes into unicode points.  You want to open the file in binary mode so that it returns `byte`'s instead of `unicode` characters.  You should also be reading fixed size data chunks from the file instead of reading line by line, which doesn't really make sense in binary mode

```
with open('/path/to/file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    val = struct.unpack('<I', f.read(4))
    if val == 123:
        ...
```

Also, 'BTH0' is not an unsigned integer, so it's never going to compare equal to the value unpacked from your binary file with the format string `<I`, which will always be an unsigned integer.